# Add sheet name to last row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There are two sheets, one named "Original" and one named "User1"

I would like a menu item for the user to click on. What I would like to happen is for the active sheet's name [User1] to be added to the last row in the last column of the "Original" sheet.

Unfortunately, I do not have any code as GAS seems to be hit/miss on documentation and literally I have found nothing in the Google Product Forums about doing this function.

Edit: I have made a functionality change and would like the sheet name to be added to the first row in column J. However, it's not working as I thought it would. Any help?

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
     .createMenu('My Menu')
     .addItem('Store Active Sheet Name', 'getActiveSheetName')
  .addToUi();
}


function getActiveSheetName() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var active_sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var active_sheet_name = active_sheet.getSheetName();

    var target_sheet_name = 'GroupA';
    var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(target_sheet_name);
    var target_sheet_lastrow = target_sheet.getLastRow()+1
    var target_sheet_lastcolumn = target_sheet.getLastColumn()
    var firstFreeRow = parseInt(getLastRowInColumn(target_sheet_name, "J:J")) + 1
    //var range = target_sheet.getRange(target_sheet_lastrow,target_sheet_lastcolumn);
    var range = target_sheet.getRange(firstFreeRow,target_sheet_lastcolumn);

    range.setValue(active_sheet_name);
}

function getLastRowInColumn(sheetObj, range) {
   return sheetObj.getRange(range)
            .getValues().filter (String).length
}
```

Comment: @Cooper Calendar Service?

Comment: See [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Comment: Lol "hit/miss on documentation". No, the APIs are extensively documented. There is even in-editor autocomplete, with type hinting for parameters and return values. You don't see this in product forums because adding a menu and writing to a sheet are not complex tasks, and the API documentation for the methods gives you example usage as well.

Comment: New problem means new question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Open the script editor (Tools menu), paste this in, save, and refresh your sheet. You'll have to approve the menu add-on when you try to run it.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
     .createMenu('My Menu')
     .addItem('Store Active Sheet Name', 'getActiveSheetName')
  .addToUi();
}


function getActiveSheetName() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var active_sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var active_sheet_name = active_sheet.getSheetName();

    var target_sheet_name = 'Original';
    var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(target_sheet_name);
    var range = target_sheet.getRange(target_sheet.getMaxRows(),target_sheet.getMaxColumns());

    range.setValue(active_sheet_name);
}
```

EDIT: You should make sure to explain why something didn't work. Did you check the execution? What was the error message? What happened when it didn't work? Did it change the wrong cell or value or did it not even run because there was an error in the code? Answering these questions when you ask for help will let others help you better.

You copied the getLastRowInColumn function from another answer, but it has some mistakes and won't work if there are empty cells. Try the function below, which finds the first row from the bottom that doesn't have empty cells, i.e. the last row with data, and it also works if the range is not just a single column.

Also you put the sheet name as the first argument to this function. It should be the sheet *object*, target_sheet.

```
function getLastRowInColumn(sheetObj, column_range) {
   var values = sheetObj.getRange(column_range).getValues();
   for (var index = values.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
       var row_array = values[index];
       if (row_array.join("") !== "") return index + 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is really rude of OP to change the question after marking an accepted answer - new issues should be new questions. I would roll back your answer to the one that answered the original question.